# How to handle a multiple requests in Hasura graphql and Netlify?

Tags: flutter, graphql, netlify, eventtrigger, hasura

I am developing a reservation system using Flutter, Hasura graphql, and Postgres DB.

Suppose my database has two main tables, "Operation" and "Ticket"

```
"Operation" : "id", "operation_date", "seat_available".

"Ticket" : "id", "seat_no", "operation_id", "user_id".
```

In the table "Operation" I have a column named "seat_available" which is a string array that contains an available seats (e.g., ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])

When some user is reserving seats, it created a record in a table "Tickets" with "operation_id" and has not assigned any seat number yet.

I created an Event Trigger in Hasura to trigger "insert" in table "Tickets" and I used netlify as a webhook.
A netlify function is used to check the "seat_available" in the table "Operation" with specific "operation_id" in ticket and assigns a seat number for that reservation ticket.

The problem is when multiple users are reserving a seat at the same time. They got the same "seat_available" data. That makes a reservation conflict.
For example:

- User_A requests to reserve the tickets. at that time "seat_available" is "["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]" and they get the seat 1. so the operation is updated to "[**"1A"**, "2", "3", "4", "5"]
- After that User_B request to reserve the ticket, at this time the User_B get the same "seat_available" data as the User_A get which is "["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]". It should be "[**"1A"**, "2", "3", "4", "5"] that updated from User_A.

This makes User_A and User_B got the same reservation seat, which is "1A".
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by adding a `where` condition on seat_available during update. For example, you could do something like this

```sql
UPDATE operation SET seat_available = {"1A", "2", "3", "4", "5"} where id = "<operation_id>" and seat_available = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"} 
RETURNING *
```

If the query returns a row, then the update happened, and you can proceed. Otherwise you should repeat the process of getting the latest seat_available and assigning the seat.

In your example case User_A query will return a row. The User_B query will not return, since User_A query would have already updated the seat_available, and the where condition for User_B on seat_available will be false.